# ArcGIS Pro Network Analyst prioritized road map

Tags: network-analyst, routing, arcgis-pro

I'm using ArcGIS Pro Network Analyst to calculate the shortest route from all points in data set A to all points in data set B, according to a road map (shp format). The road map contains two types of roads (type 1 and type 2), both in the same file but differentiated with a variable in that data called "type".

Network Analyst calculates the shortest routes using both type 1 and 2 roads. I am wondering if there is any way to prioritize type 1 roads, such that the distance is only calculated along type 1 roads unless a point is not located along a type 1 road. In that case, type 2 roads can be used to get us to the type 1-road map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the creation process of a **Network Dataset** you are able to set the parameters a network (*Cost, Descriptors, Restrictions, Hierarchy*). Since you want to keep Type 2, but avoid it if possible, I think you are looking for the following Restriction **Avoid: High**

More information on how the set the parameters [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/understanding-network-attributes.htm)

However, it is still possible that in some case, type 2 will be used not only to reach type 1. To really respect that restriction, you may first divide your dataset into Type 1 and Type 2. Then, calculate the shortest path from Type 2 to Type 1 and then use these results to perform your main analysis to find the shortest path to points B.

Comment: In the second option, I would then need to add the type 2 roads that leads from points in data set A or B to the type 1 road map (shortest route). Is this step also possible to do within Network Analyst? Can you calculate shortest route from a point to a road map? And can you store that road and add it to another road map? Thanks!

Comment: For the first option, you can also try to build a Route layer (Network Analysis -> Make Route Layer). There is a Restriction section in this tool. For the second option, I think you can (never tried...). If you can't, just convert the vertices of your road map into points using the following tool: **convert feature vertices to points** (data management).